# Initializing PHP variable from SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I want to initialize a variable from an entry in an sql table; this entry is one I've queried for.

```
//Grab user id from users.sql
$quser = $db->query("
    SELECT *
        FROM users //in this table is a column named userident
        WHERE username = '$user' //this where conditional filters to a lone row         
");*/
```

I tried `$var = $quser["ident"];` since this is how I would display table entries in a `foreach()` loop, but this doesn't seem to work.

There is only one ident entry per user, so when I filter the query with where, it results in one row. Why can't I grab the entry and place in a variable?

Comment: Disregard the end-comment at the end; I commented this segment of code out so I could work on other things in the meantime.

Comment: You say `in this table is a column named userident` but you use `$quser["ident"]`

Comment: Sorry, I'm renaming things as I go along. I'm trying to get the entry under `ident` in the lone row.

Comment: Is this pure PHP or CodeIgniter?

Comment: Pure PHP; I'm using PDO in conjunction, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do

1. Execute the query
2. Pick up the first row (as there will be only one row this'll work otherwise do it in a loop)
3. Get the column from the row produced

Here's an example

```
    $quser = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");
    $first_row=$quser->row();

    $reqdData=$first_row->ident; // Or whateber column you need
```

Comment: i think above solution is perfect but one patch i would like to add
 

$reqdData=($first_row->num_rows() > 0)?$first_row->ident :0;

Comment: With this I get a `Call to undefined method PDOStatement::row()` error.